# Convergence uniform of the sequence $\sin(nz)/n$

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

I would like to find the maximal open set such that $(\frac{\sin(nz)}{n})_{n}$ converge uniformly on $\Bbb{C}.$

We have $$\sin(nz)=i\times\frac{e^{-inx}e^{ny}-e^{inx}e^{-ny}}{2}$$ so that $$\frac{\sin(nz)}{n}=i\times\frac{e^{-inx}e^{ny}-e^{inx}e^{-ny}}{2n}$$

Now I have $$\vert\frac{\sin(nz)}{n}\vert\le \frac{e^{ny}+e^{-ny}}{2n}$$

If $y\ge 0$ or $y\le 0$ then the RHS tend to $+\infty,$ so not sure what I have to do.

Comment: It's certainly better to do the more direct estimation $|sin(nz)/n| \leq 1/n$. Your right hand side grows very fast unless $n=0$.

Comment: @md2perpe That holds only for real $z$. If $\operatorname{Im} z \neq 0$, then $\lvert \sin (nz)\rvert$ grows exponentially.

Comment: @md2perpe $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: Since $\lvert \sin (nz)\rvert \sim \frac{1}{2} e^{n\lvert\operatorname{Im} z\rvert}$, the sequence converges only for real $z$. The maximal _open_ subset of $\mathbb{C}$ on which it converges is thus $\varnothing$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I suppose we can do the same for $\cos(nz)/n$ ? And thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same for $\cos$.

Comment: @DanielFischer if we have $e^{nz}/n$ then the maximal open set is the half left plane but for $cos(nz)/n$ and $sin(nz)/n$ is $\emptyset$, that's funny.

Comment: In $\sin$ and $\cos$, the exponent occurs with both signs. So whenever one of the terms is small, the other one is large. On the real axis, both exponential terms remain bounded, but off it, one grows exponentially and the other shrinks exponentially.